# how to pass multiple array data into a table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

here i am having two arrays in the url and i need to display as shown in image [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R55oT.png) and i don't know any idea how to implement this in table view as shown in image

```
{
  "Flat": [
    {
      "price": "$5.00", 
      "id": 11, 
      "name": "Fixed"
    }
  ], 
  "United Parcel Service": [
    {
      "price": "$109.12", 
      "id": 1, 
      "name": "worldwide Expedited"
    }, 
    {
      "price": "$120.18", 
      "id": 2, 
      "name": "worldwide Express saver"
    }
  ]
} 


class shippingObject: NSObject {
var id :NSInteger!
var name :String!
var price : String!
}
 class CheckoutViewController: 
 UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ContinueButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var newAddress: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var tableDetails: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var shippingTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var HeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
let url = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bMlqRPbjGW?indent=2"
let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVWKKHtWbm?indent=2"
var detailsArray : [shippingObject] = []
var shippingArray :[[String: AnyObject]] = []
var price = [String]()
var keys = [String]()
var name = [String]()
var methodArray : [[String: AnyObject]] = []
let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
var arrayss =  [String:Any]()
var checkIsRadioSelect = [Int]()
var checkIsButtonEnable = [Int]()
var checkIsPaymentRadioSelect = [Int]()
let response : [Int] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableDetails.isHidden = true
    shippingTableView.isHidden = true
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    titleLabel.isHidden = true
    newAddress.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    ContinueButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    myActivityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 320, width: 30, height: 30)
    myActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)
    myActivityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myActivityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)
    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myActivityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
    self.shippingmethodURL()
    self.shippingaddressURL()
    tableDetails.delegate = self
    tableDetails.dataSource = self
    tableDetails.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableDetails.estimatedRowHeight = 300
    shippingTableView.delegate = self
    shippingTableView.dataSource = self
    shippingTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    shippingTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}    
func shippingaddressURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
        self.shippingArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "address") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.tableDetails.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
func assignValuesToObjecs(arrayvalues: NSArray){
    (arrayvalues as NSArray).enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in

        let Object :shippingObject = shippingObject()

        Object.name = (object as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "name") as! String
        Object.id = (object as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "id") as! NSInteger
        Object.price = (object as AnyObject).value(forKey: "price")as! String
        self.detailsArray.append(Object)
    })
}

func shippingmethodURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string: self.urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {    print(jsonObj!)
            self.arrayss = jsonObj as! [String : Any]
            print(self.arrayss)
            //self.shippingArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Flat") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
            self.assignValuesToObjecs(arrayvalues :(jsonObj?["Flat"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]! as? NSArray)!)
            self.assignValuesToObjecs(arrayvalues :(jsonObj?["United Parcel Service"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]! as? NSArray)!)
            self.methodArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "United Parcel Service") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.keys = ["Flat","United Parcel Service"]
                self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
@IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
    let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: sender.tag)
    _ = self.checkIsButtonEnable.index(of: sender.tag)
    if sender.isSelected {
        shippingTableView.isHidden = false
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        titleLabel.isHidden = false

    } else{
        if(chekIndex == nil){
            self.checkIsRadioSelect.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.checkIsRadioSelect.append(sender.tag)
            self.checkIsButtonEnable.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.checkIsButtonEnable.append(sender.tag)
            self.tableDetails.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
    var count = 0
    if tableView.tag == 100{
        return 1
    }
    else if tableView.tag == 110 {
        return arrayss.count
    }
    return count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if tableView.tag == 100{
        return "SHIPPING ADDRESS"
    }
    else  {
        return self.keys[section]
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){
    if tableView.tag == 100 {
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)
    }
    else {
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.tintColor = UIColor.white
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    if tableView.tag == 100{
        return shippingArray.count
    }
    else {
        var key = self.keys[section]
        print(key)
        var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
        return a.count
    }
}
@IBAction func continueButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "payment") as! paymentMethodViewController
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}

@IBAction func deleteAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    shippingArray.remove(at:sender.tag)
    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView.tag == 100{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! addressTableViewCell
        tableDetails.isHidden = false
        myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        let arr = shippingArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.nameLabel.text = arr["name"] as? String
        cell.addressLabel.text = arr["address"]as? String
        let mobilenumber : Int =  arr["number"] as! Int
        cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = String(describing: mobilenumber)
        cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.editButton.isHidden = true
        cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
        let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
        if(checkIndex != nil){
            shippingTableView.isHidden = false
            scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
            titleLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
            cell.editButton.isHidden = false
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
        }else{
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
            cell.editButton.isHidden = true
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
        }
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingCell", for: indexPath) as! shippingMethodTableViewCell
 //            let arr = detailsArray[indexPath.row]
 //            cell.methodNameLabel.text = arr.name
 //            cell.priceLabel.text = arr.price
        var key = self.keys[indexPath.section]
        print(key)
        var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
        var dictionary = a[indexPath.row];
        cell.methodNameLabel.text = dictionary ["name"] + dictionary ["price"]
        return cell
    }
}
```

any help would be of great appreciation

Comment: image link dead

Comment: Each key from your outer dictionary should be a section title, with the corresponding array providing the entries for that section

Comment: image link is working @LalKrishna

Comment: yes how to implement this ? @Paulw11

Comment: Add implementations for `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource` functions.

Comment: i had implemented that but in no. of rows in section i need to give count how to give that ? @meaning-matters

Comment: i am new to swift so i don't know how to get the data as mentioned in image link above @meaning-matters

Comment: but i didn't got the tutorials for how to pass multiple array data to a table view ? @meaning-matters

Comment: as @Paulw11 commented Sectional table view can help you. I have added ans. Do let me know if it works.As I couldnt check the same.  Apologies for format and syntax as I am away from my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sectional UITableView can rescue you from such situation. I have assumed arrayss as dictionary and jsonObj.

```
// number of rows in table view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var key= self.keys[section]
    print(key)
    var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
     return a.count
 }
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2  // if not fixed self.keys.count or self.arrayss.count
}

// create a cell for each table view row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!
   var key= self.keys[indexPath.section]
   print(key)
   var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
   var dictionary = a[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any];
   cell.textLabel.text = dictionary ["name"]+ dictionary ["price"]  // you can set the text from the data model

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.keys[section]
}
```

---- EDIT----

In order to get all keys and values of dictionary from a dictionary separately.

```
 var key = Array(arrayss.keys).sorted(by: >)
 var values = Array(arrayss.values).sorted(by: >)
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Comment: what problem u are facing

Comment: i tried ur code but its showing error in no. of rows in section

Comment: i need to implement flat and united parcel service as shown in image https://i.stack.imgur.com/R55oT.png

Comment: i need to display the dictionaries in the flat and united parcel service below their sections as shown in image link

Comment: i understand what you want. have u defined arrayss as Dictionary. I have assumed it to be dictionary.

Comment: i had declared arrayss as array

Comment: i had completed upto this in image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6DO6.png  but not got as expected

Comment: If doesnot effect much of your work , try declaring arrayss  as dictionary and  copy jsonObj to it as dictionary

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/Z6DO6.png this is happening as you have returned detailsArray.count asnumberOfRowsInSection  method. Hence you are getting 3 rows in both section.

Comment: i declared as an array but it is getting error bad instruction

Comment: any help  ? @luckyShubra

Comment: in your assignValuesToObjecs you are adding "Flats" as well as "United Parcel Service" objects in your detailsArray. Hence it gets three values for both section.Therefore you need to save with keys and use it to return in numberOfRowsInSection as I have done above. then u can replace where I have used arrayss with detailsArray then.You can achieve this task by using dictionary.

Comment: or you can declare arrayss  as dictionary , it would help.

Comment: can u show me your number of section and  numberOfRowsInSection  ??

Comment: i am getting error in shipping method function i.e. bad instruction where i used arrayss after changing it to dictionary

Comment: func shippingmethodURL() ??  I cant finnd arrayss  there?

Comment: self.arrayss = (jsonObj?.allKeys)! as! [String] this i used in function to get keyys from a dictionary

Comment: You have declared arrayss as dictionary, but tring to assign array to it thats why the error. self.arrayss = jsonObj as jsonObj is dictionary

Comment: should i need to change this ?

Comment: declare var arrayss = [String:Any]() and change the above

Comment: but when i given like this then i got error in title for header section i.e https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD8JP.png as shown in link

Comment: if possible can i have ur mail id ?

Comment: developershubhra@gmail.com

Comment: bro i got the required layout but how to pass data https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi5AP.png

Comment: update working code. it would helpful for further discussion.

Comment: update working code. it would helpful for further discussion.

Comment: you can pass data as discussed above in  cellForRowAtIndexPath or you can even  utilisse your models for the same.

Comment: when i use ur mentioned cell for row at indexpath then its showing error

Comment: u need to force cast dictionary as dictionary. Change it to var dictionary = a[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]

Comment: var a is not an dictionary its an array

Comment: var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
   var dictionary = a[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any];
   cell.textLabel.text = dictionary ["name"]+ dictionary ["price"]

Comment: got it bro but we are passing the flat and united parcel service as static how to pass it dynamically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148117/discussion-between-luckyshubhra-and-thiru).

Comment: that means if i got more than two then how it need to be updated i.e is array names flat and united parcel service i am saying

Comment: Then instead of hardcoding your keys , you can do it as var keys = Array(arrayss.keys).sorted(by: >)

Comment: bro do u have any idea of reducing or increasing  table view height dynamically